# How to format the individual <td> columns in the <MvcMovie.Models.Movie> example

Tags: html, css, formatting

I am starting to tinker with C#. This is my first grassroots project.

I have been working through the MVC example for a week and overcome most of my learning challenges. What I can't get the hang of is how to apply a CSS formatting strategy for the data returned from a DB call (other than to write very messy call-specific HTML).

I am going to use a sample from w3schools.com (https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border_divider) as the sample because it is nicely contained.

Using this example I want to be able to Left-Align the first column, Center the second column, and Right-Align with a `# ##0.00` format the value column.

I assume there is something I need to do in this code to distinguish between Column 1, 2 & 3 (but can't find what it is):

```
th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

The complete listing of the code from w3schools.com is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Bordered Table Dividers</h2>
<p>Add the border-bottom property to th and td for horizontal dividers:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial I am working through is this one, but I have resolved what I could within this example (so it should probably be ignored)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some demonstration CSS to show how to tackle this referencing problem. Click on the "Run" button to see it in action.

Although you could add classes onto each `<td>` tag, it is easier to specify which child of the `tr` you want. To do this, you can use pseudo-classes `first-child`, `nth-child`, and `last-child`. I have added some random formatting to your example - I will leave the specific formatting definitions to you.

You could of course use `nth-child` for all of these. Often, enumerations in programming start from zero ("zero-indexed") but this class is one-indexed. Thus, for `first-child` I could have used `nth-child(1)` instead. In a similar way, `last-child` could be written here as `nth-child(3)`, but that may be less maintainable in some cases, since if you want to insert a column, you would have to adjust the CSS for the rightmost one too.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table tr td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: purple;
}
table tr td:last-child {
    font-style: italic;
    color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Bordered Table Dividers</h2>
<p>Add the border-bottom property to th and td for horizontal dividers:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td>Brown</td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

### Further reading

Classes used:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

These are all pseudo-classes that have a special meaning. You can learn more about these here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: That is a very smart solution - thank you. I had in the interim created a class, and applied that class to the individual cells. However your solution allows me to simply use the column number offset - a much more streamline way of extending this into the actual application I am working towards.

Comment: No worries @RobertAustin, happy to have helped `:-)`